# Derivation of maxwell's equations - how to make it mathematically correct?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

So, we started from
$$\oint \vec{E}d\vec{A}=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$
And used an electric dipole setup with $\vec{p}=q\vec{l}$ and $\vec{P}=\frac{\sum\vec{p}}{V}$, and reached the desired result:
$$\oint \vec{D}d\vec{A}=Q_{real}$$
But I was thinking about an easier way. Formally:
$$Q_{polarization}=\frac{\vec{p}}{\vec{l}}=\frac{\vec{P}V}{\vec{l}}=\vec{P}\vec{A}$$
But it's not correct mathematically. I think I should do some infinitesimal calculations to get $Q_{p}=\int \vec{P} d \vec{A}$, but how should I do it?

Comment: Well one problem is that you cannot divide by a vector...

Comment: @AaronStevens As I wrote, it's a formal, mathematically not correct derivation.

Comment: Maybe you could try rewriting as $q l\hat l$?

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v2): Replace the word _Maxwell's equations_ with the word _Gauss' law_ in various places.